# Can we get a servo/stepper motor, which can rotate in steps of 0.5 degree.

Tags: stepper-motor, servo

I am looking for a servo/stepper motor which can rotate in small steps of **0.5 degree**. I have tried with the **sg90** tower pro micro servo, but it doesn't rotate in steps of 0.5, rather it does in steps of **1 degree**. I am also looking for a **compact/light weight motor**. Could any one please suggest such motors.

Comment: If you look for stepper on fleaBay, you find the 'world's most popular stepper?', something like 28Y something or other, that moves in 2048 full steps per turn. If you aggregate several steps, then you can get 720 steps per turn with no cummulative error. Besides, recommendation for specific products are OT and you can expect to be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have microstepping driver for that. A normal stepper moves for 1.8° at full step, half step is 0.9, quarter step is 0.45°. 
If you need exactly 0.5° then consider using a mechanical transmission of ratio 3.6. 1.8/3.6 = 0.5

Comment: Not 0.5 degree exactly, but anything below 0.75 would do good.

Comment: Then any stepper motor + driver that you will pick nowadays is capable of that. The driver has to be microstepping capable.

Comment: Can i get any useful link, so that i can explain it to my group?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tRoT3qpndbU


http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00822a.pdf


http://hackaday.com/2016/08/29/how-accurate-is-microstepping-really/